# How to properly model tables in Cassandra (from a SQL mind set to Cassandra)?

Tags: sql, database-design, cassandra

I'm trying Cassandra and I'm still trying to switch my brain to this column-based logic.

I've watched a couple of videos and tried to mimic what they talked about... video storage, weather information, etc, but I keep getting errors.

- Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown
  definition postid referenced in PRIMARY KEY"
- Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Missing CLUSTERING ORDER for column
  postid"

I tried only users, tags and posts. I can easily imagine that there is something I don't understand.

```
CREATE TABLE users( 
  userId uuid, 
  login map<int, text>, 
  email text, 
  phoneNumber text, 
  emailVerified boolean, 
  phoneNumberVerified boolean, 
  firstName text, 
  lastName text, 
  gender text, 
  country text, 
  region text, 
  city text, 
  cityId int, 
  zipcode text, 
  password text, 
  passwordSetDate timestamp, 
  createdAt timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((email, phoneNumber, userId), lastName, createdAt)
);
CREATE TABLE tags( 
  tag text, 
  itemId uuid, 
  itemType text, 
  createdAt timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((tag), itemId)
);
CREATE TABLE posts( 
  postId uuid, 
  authorId uuid, 
  authorName text, 
  content text, 
  tags set<text>, 
  createdAt timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((authorId, postId), createdAt)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdAt DESC);
CREATE TABLE comments( 
  commentId uuid, 
  postId uuid, 
  authorName text, 
  authorId uuid, 
  content text, 
  createdAt timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((authorId), postId)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdAt DESC);
CREATE TABLE messages( 
  channelId uuid, 
  messageId uuid, 
  authorId uuid, 
  authorName text, 
  content text,
  tags set<text>, 
  time timeuuid, 
  createdAt Timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((channelId, authorId), messageId)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);
CREATE TABLE channels( 
  channelId uuid, 
  content text, 
  createdAt Timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((channelId, authorId), messageId)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);
CREATE TABLE media( 
  mediaId uuid, 
  userId uuid, 
  userEmail text, 
  type text, 
  description text, 
  size text, 
  mime text, 
  tags set<text>, 
  createdAt Timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((channel_id), message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);
CREATE TABLE loginLog( 
  eventId timeuuid, 
  login text, 
  createdAt timestamp, 
  status text, 
  ip inet, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((eventId, ip), message_id)
);
CREATE TABLE weatherByCities( 
  cityId int, 
  date text, 
  city text, 
  createdAt timestamp, 
  PRIMARY KEY ((cityId, date), createdAt)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdAt DESC);
```

Could someone explain what I don't understand? Where is the flaw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several severe typo, invalid column definition exists in your queries: Here are some of them:

> `CREATE TABLE comments( 
>     commentId uuid, 
>     postId uuid, 
>     authorName text, 
>     authorId uuid, 
>     content text, 
>     createdAt timestamp, 
>     PRIMARY KEY ((authorId), postId)
>   ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdAt DESC);`

Here **WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (createdAt DESC);**  **`createdAt`** column is not a clustering key. It should be **postId**.

> `CREATE TABLE messages( 
>     channelId uuid, 
>     messageId uuid, 
>     authorId uuid, 
>     authorName text, 
>     content text,
>     tags set<text>, 
>     time timeuuid, 
>     createdAt Timestamp, 
>     PRIMARY KEY ((channelId, authorId), messageId)
>   ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);`

Here **message_id** does not exists, it should be **messageId**.

Same things also goes to media:

> `CREATE TABLE media( 
>     mediaId uuid, 
>     userId uuid, 
>     userEmail text, 
>     type text, 
>     description text, 
>     size text, 
>     mime text, 
>     tags set<text>, 
>     createdAt Timestamp, 
>     PRIMARY KEY ((channel_id), message_id)
>   ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id DESC);`

**channel_id, message_id** does not exists.

I guess you already get the idea what you have done wrong. Now carefully find other typos and fix them.

Comment: Oh yea ok about the typ - I noticed but I though I changed them. And now I understand, WITH CLUSTERING ORDER shoudl refer to a key. Duh. I'll get the hang of it. Thanks for your inputs.